# Best way to create physics body for a maze in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm new to SpriteKit and iOS programming. I've been working on a new project about maze game using SpriteKit. I can't find any good way to create a Physics Body for my maze. I've tried this awesome tool [SKPhysicsBody Path Generator](http://dazchong.com/spritekit/) but it didn't work, maybe because my maze was not in a "convex polygonal path" as the rules required (I'm not sure, I've tried a simple .png image with an upside down T shape). Is there any other way to do this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my solution here, more simple and powerful:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/49502/procedural-level-generation-in-games-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 2):

Try Apple's approach, as they did in Adventure Game:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/BuildingtheWorld/BuildingtheWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013140-CH3-SW1

**Reading the Map** Section